# If the img src is correct add css to the img tag so its display none

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a jquery that simply check if there is any img tags with a specific src and if there is any that img should get display: none with css. I want it to iterate throught the page and do it to all img tags

But I cant seem to get it to work.

This is what I tried

```
$('img([src^="/_layouts/15/images/ikk/news/image.jpg"])').each(function () {
        $(this).css("display", "none");
    });
```

Html:

```
<img alt="" src="/_layouts/15/images/ikk/news/image.jpg">
```

Note: there can be many img tags with this url generated so I need to iterate and check.

Comment: can you post html structure or can provide JSfiddle for it?

Comment: why parens around `[src]`?

Comment: @user1737909 it's jQuery's selector.

Comment: I know that. But `img([src])` is a syntax error, even in jQuery.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor but here selector is wrong that's what he meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You make a mistake, don't add `()` in the first `img` selector!

```
$('img[src^="/_layouts/15/images/ikk/news/image.jpg"]').each(function () {
    //$('.latest-news-container img').css("display", "none");
    //and just use
    $(this).hide();
});
```

And if you just wan't to hide selected img do:

```
$('img[src^="/_layouts/15/images/ikk/news/image.jpg"]').hide();
```

Comment: I did some changes to the question

Comment: @Obsivus post the div html too. as your current one is not clear to see which div you are talking about. its `sibling` or `parent`.

Comment: Likewise, if you wan't to select only hidden img, you can use this selector `$('img[src^="/_layouts/15/images/ikk/news/image.jpg"]:hidden')`

Answer (score 0):

check the working fiddle for it here
you have provided a wrong selector.

it should be

```
$("img[src.....]")
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tWdQt/)**